# How do I use setTimeout function in my JS script

Tags: javascript, airtable

I'm trying to create a script in Airtable linked to a button. The process is as follows:

1. Button within Airtable pressed
2. If the checkbox field 'Jira switch' is false, then turn it to true
3. Wait for 2 seconds, reset the field to false

This is the script I've written using the setTimeout() function:

```
let table = base.getTable("XOS"); //The name of the table you're in here
let record = await input.recordAsync('Pick a record', table);
if (record) {
   
 if (record.getCellValue("Jira switch")===false) {
    table.updateRecordAsync(record, {'Jira switch': true});
    output.text('checkbox ticked');
 } 
 
const myTimeout = setTimeout(timeDelay, 2000);
   function timeDelay()
      table.updateRecordAsync(record, {'Jira switch': false});
      output.text('2 second interval');
    
}
```

When I write the code I get an error that says *"cannot find name setTimeout"*. As a solution, it suggests *"add missing function declaration 'setTimeout'"*

How do I declare this function so it can function with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think ther is a problem in your syntax.
After `function timeDelay()` you forgot to add curly bracket to declare what code are inside the function.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This answer was already given, please delete yours.

Answer (score 0):

missing curly bracket`{`

and what is `if(record){`doing or where is closing  of it`}`?

```js
let table = base.getTable("XOS"); //The name of the table you're in here
let record = await input.recordAsync('Pick a record', table);
   /*if (record) {*========> where is it ending*/ 
 if (record.getCellValue("Jira switch")===false) {
    table.updateRecordAsync(record, {'Jira switch': true});
    output.text('checkbox ticked');
 } 
 
const myTimeout = setTimeout(timeDelay, 2000);
   function timeDelay() {/*========> missing curly bracket*/
      table.updateRecordAsync(record, {'Jira switch': false});
      output.text('2 second interval');
    
}
```